# How to retrieve a specific data in Firebase Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

After a user signed in his/her account, he/she will be ask what is his/her user role.

IMG 1: ask user role

[image]

After selecting a role, it will then be save in the database,

IMG 2: saved user role

[image]

So, how do we retrieve the specific data from Firebase database and then print it in the HTML?

IMG 3: show the user role

[image]

These are the codes I used in my .js

```
function app(user){

  function updateMyStatus(e){
    var myUpdate={};
    myUpdate.email = user.email;
    myUpdate.displayName = user.displayName;
    myUpdate.status = document.getElementById("clientStatus").value;
    fb.child(user.uid).set(myUpdate);
  }
  function receiveUpdate(received){
    var data = received.val();
    console.log( data );
    document.getElementById('role').innerHTML= "";
  }
  document.getElementById('userName').innerHTML = user.displayName;
  var fb = firebase.database().ref('Accounts');

  document.getElementById("clientStatus")
    .addEventListener("input",updateMyStatus);
}
```

and if the user has already a user role(status) as shown in the image 2, how do you hide the Dropbox that is shown in the image 1?

Answer (score 1):

The below will get back your data from Firebase for that account. Then it is a matter of setting the values to their respective HTML elements.

```
fb.child(AccountId).on(‘value’, callbackFunction)
```

For reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: Which function should I put it? Under the receivedUpdate()?

Answer (score 1):

```
function receiveUpdate(received){
    var data = received.val();
    console.log( data );
    document.getElementById('role').innerHTML= "";
    //hide the dropdown box 
    document.getElementById("clientStatus").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("clientStatus").addEventListener("input",updateMyStatus);
//put this under your other event listener
fb.child('Accounts').on(‘value’, receiveUpdate);
```

This code will not work as written. I hope this helps give you a good idea.

Comment: What is this for? Retrieving data or hiding the dropbox if the user has a role? Im using my phone right now

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current code, and based on my own understanding of the Firebase Realtime Database, these are the steps you need to take:

- Register a listener to listen for changes to the database
- To be more specific, you need to add a listener to the particular field that you are interested in in the database.
- This listener should preferably not be inside any function.
- This listener would check whether a role exists for your user in the database.

  1. If yes, hide the input field and display user's details.
  2. Else, display both the input field and the user's details.

As I have no experience using the Realtime Database (I have only used Cloud Firestore before), I am not very familiar with its syntax. But the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) suggested by @Andre Kool and @thezachcannon in the previous post has examples of adding a listener to a particular database reference.

Hope that helped.